# RestKit POST object with many to many relationship and two parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit, afnetworking

I'm using RestKit with MagicalRecord. I have a many-to-many relationship in my app.

The relationship is between two entitnies: User and Tag. A user can follow multiple tags and at the same time a given tag can be followed by multiple users (I'm caching users and tags in my local database).

My REST API has the following method:

```
POST http://api.xyz.com/v1/users/{user}/tags/{tag}
```

It lets me tell the server that the user has started following a given tag. The {user} and {tag} parts are parameters which represent the ID's of those entities.

I don't know how to:

1. Map the relationship in the `RKObjectManager`.
2. Post that update to the server.

Comment: What did you try? `RKRoute`?

Comment: I've tried RKRoute. I also forgot to mention that there is another POST path for the Tag entity - POST http://api.xyz.com/v1/tags...

Comment: Add the code you tried to the question and explain what it does wrong